# Why Rails Migration fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration, uuid

I'm using uuid instead of bigint as primaty key. And next migration

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :projects, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

fails with error:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  foreign key constraint "fk_rails_b872a6760a" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns "user_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: bigint and uuid.
```

Comment: May be this helps https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23422

Comment: @Salil In particular [rafaecheve's comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23422#issuecomment-194009911) which suggests `t.belongs_to ... type: :uuid` (PS: `t.belongs_to` is an alias for `t.references`).

Answer (score 24):

`t.references` by default assumes the other table has a `bigint` primary key and makes the foreign key field also a `bigint`. Once the foreign key is added, this discrepancy is revealed and the migration fails.

Use `type: :uuid` to specify that the column should indeed be a `uuid`.

```
t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true, type: :uuid
```

I myself in my projects keep track of it by remembering that every references/belongs to needs to have 4 options. `null`, `foreign_key`, `type` and `index`. That forces me to think about each of the 4 options even if I choose to leave their values as defaults.

Comment: You're my Hero ! Thank you